# Create series based on two pandas dataframe bool columns

Tags: pandas

How do I create a series based on two pandas dataframe bool columns?

```
    round_up  round_down is_round_up is_round_down High     Low
0   0.75       0.7       False       True          0.70532  0.69818
1   0.75       0.7       False       True          0.70196  0.67268
2   0.75       0.7       False       True          0.71243  0.69938
3   0.75       0.7       False       True          0.70226  0.69884
4   0.75       0.7       False       True          0.70292  0.69952
5   0.75       0.7       True        True          0.75100  0.69000
```

**Desired output** is a series with `round_up` if `is_round_up` or `round_down` if `is_round_down` or if both `True` select `is_round_up`.

```
0 0.70
1 0.70
2 0.70
3 0.70
4 0.70
5 0.75
```

**Test data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'round_up': {0: 0.75,
  1: 0.75,
  2: 0.75,
  3: 0.75,
  4: 0.75,
  5: 0.75},
 'round_down': {0: 0.70,
  1: 0.70,
  2: 0.70,
  3: 0.70,
  4: 0.70,
  5: 0.70},
 'is_round_up': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False, 5:True},
 'is_round_down': {0: True, 1: True, 2: True, 3: True, 4: True, 5:True},
 'High': {0: 0.70532, 1: 0.70196, 2: 0.71243, 3: 0.70226, 4: 0.70292, 5:0.751},
 'Low': {0: 0.69818, 1: 0.67268, 2: 0.69938, 3: 0.69884, 4: 0.69952, 5:0.69}})
```

Edit: To clarify if both columns are `False` I would expect to see `Nan` for that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the columns in order of choice (up is preferred to down in case of both True), mask the False values, `bfill` and get the first column.

Advantage: the solution is scalable to any number of columns.

```
(df[['round_up', 'round_down']]
 .where(df[['is_round_up', 'is_round_down']].values)
 .bfill(axis=1)
 .iloc[:,0]
 .rename('result')
)
```

output:

```
0    0.70
1    0.70
2    0.70
3    0.70
4    0.70
5    0.75
Name: result, dtype: float64
```